# How to split xts data half yearly

Tags: r

I want to split xts data into half years. I have tried split.xts() and split(). Also tell me how i can split by rows like 1:6,6:12,12:18 etc.

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
split.xts(dataframe,f=)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the following manner.

```
test1<-split(data_xts, rep(1:ceiling(nrow(data_xts)/6), each=6,length.out=nrow(data_xts)))
```